# function return Java Script

Tags: javascript, funções, return

Eu Pesquisei bastante sobre callbacks and asynchronous no javascript.

A function HelloWorld.prototype.getCont pesquisa o ID de uma conta e retorna um numero EX: 1; 
A function HelloWorld.prototype.getAllAccounts Deve obter o numero do resultado ex (1) e obter todos os dados da conta, mas ele roda a função, mostra o resultado mas não salva na variavel;
Porque ele não salva e como posso fazer para ele salvar?

Aqui é onde ele deveria obter o resultado, mas ele apenas roda a função e não salva o retorno.

> var IDMembro =  this.getCont(); //SHOW DATA AGAIN

refornçando, como obtenho uma variavel com os dados salvos?

> ```
> HelloWorld.prototype.getCont = function(cb) { //GetCont é um objeto Função
>  var MyAddress = window.web3.eth.accounts[0];
>  document.getElementById("Address").innerHTML =  MyAddress ;
>          this.instance.AccountAddress(MyAddress, function (error, result) {      
>   document.getElementById("IDAccount").innerHTML =  result ;
>  console.log (result); //DATA OK
>  return result; 
> });  
> }
>
>
> HelloWorld.prototype.getAllAccounts = function(cb) {
>        var IDMembro =  this.getCont(); //SHOW DATA AGAIN
>  console.log (IDMembro); //VALUE INDEFINED??
>
>           this.instance.AllAccounts(1, function (error, result) {      
>  document.getElementById("AllAccounts0").innerHTML =  result[0];
>   document.getElementById("AllAccounts1").innerHTML =  result[1];
>    document.getElementById("AllAccounts2").innerHTML =  result[2];
>     document.getElementById("AllAccounts3").innerHTML =  result[3];
>      document.getElementById("AllAccounts4").innerHTML =  result[4];
>       document.getElementById("AllAccounts5").innerHTML =  result[5]; 
>
>   });
>
> }
> ```

//____________________________________________________________
no console ele me volta esses dados em formato de array.

> e {s: 1, e: 0, c: Array(1)}c: [1]e: 0s: 1__proto__: Object

mas tenho um outro bloco que ele volta o valor apenas com result.
isso é uma conta cadastrada na blockchain. ee deve voltar o ID da conta no caso o numero 1 mas sempre volta indefinido nesse bloco. mas em outro bloco ele volta normal.

//_____________________________________________________________
Fazendo assim acho que fica mais facil de tentar enteder pois agora tenho duas funções dentro de uma.
no meu banco de dados está assim:
Endereco de email | ID Membro;

Eu preciso buscar o ID do membro pelo endereço de email que ele me fornecer.

Dentro da função getCont existe uma variavel local, dois obejetos e duas funções;

O ID member é uma variavel local da função getCont e recebe indefinido.
endereco é uma variavel local que representa o email informado pelo usuario.

o AccountAddress é o objeto com o nome dado para minha estrutura no banco de dados, a variavel endereço busca um valor do IDMembro;

ex: busca endereco de email teste@teste.com e retorna o  ID member e define a variavel IDMember que no exemplo deve ser 1; 1º membro cadastro.
e IDMember agora é definido;
Até aí tudo funciona.

agora vem o problema:
quando pego o IDMember que está no scopo local e faço console.log fora do objeto AccountAddress, ele automaticamente volta indefinido.

Eu entendi que tem a sicronia e callback... blz, como posso fazer callback do objeto AccountAddress já que, ele possui uma função e um retorno? segue o codigo a abaixo:

Muito Obrigado

> HelloWorld.prototype.getCont = function(cb) {  var IDMember; var
>   endereco = window.web3.eth.accounts[0] ;
>
> document.getElementById("Address").innerHTML =  endereco;
>            this.instance.AccountAddress(endereco, function (error, result) {
>         var IDMember = result;   document.getElementById("IDAccount").innerHTML =  IDMember ;
>   console.log(IDMember);
>
> }) console.log(IDMember); }

Comment: Marcio esse é o site da SO em português, traduza sua pergunta

Comment: traduzido Ricardo, achei que em ingles a resposta chegaria mais rapido :) muito obrigado pela dica

Answer (score 1):

O problema é o escopo do resultado, ele está dentro de uma função que está dentro de outra função que está sendo chamada por outra função, segue um exemplo de código em que getCont passa a ter um retorno de resultado.

```
HelloWorld.prototype.getCont = function(cb) { //GetCont é um objeto Função
     var MyAddress = window.web3.eth.accounts[0],
         resultado; // escopo de HelloWorld.prototype.getCont

     document.getElementById("Address").innerHTML =  MyAddress ;
     this.instance.AccountAddress(MyAddress, function (error, result) {      
         document.getElementById("IDAccount").innerHTML =  result ;
         console.log (result); //DATA OK
         resultado = result; // para ter acesso no escopo externo
         return result; // escopo de function (error, result) {
     });  

     return resultado; // escopo de HelloWorld.prototype.getCont
};
```

Com o exemplo após as edições, usando uma função de callback:

```
var funcaoCallback = function(idMember) {
    // faça algo com idMember
};

HelloWorld.prototype.getCont = function(cb) { 
    var IDMember; 
    var endereco = window.web3.eth.accounts[0] ;

    document.getElementById("Address").innerHTML = endereco; 
    this.instance.AccountAddress(endereco, function (error, result) {
        var IDMember = result; 
        document.getElementById("IDAccount").innerHTML = IDMember ;
        console.log(IDMember);
        funcaoCallback(IDMember); // usando callback
   }); 

   console.log(IDMember); 
}
```

Comment: Se `AccountAddress` for assíncrono este código está errado... pois a função vai dar `return` antes de `resultado` receber o valor de `result`.

Comment: Sim, por isso que não aconselhei a dar return diretamente em this.instance.AccountAddress, pois o código desse método não foi exibido, mas a resposta é válida, independente do que acontece em AccountAddress, ele tem que mudar o escopo.

Comment: Não funcionou :( eu tinha tentando criar uma variavel local fora do scopo do AccountAddress. mas mesmo assim ele não volta o valor. toda vez que coloco uma variavel entre "     });  ",  ele volta indefinido. acho que ele está lendo primeiro todas variaveis fora da função e depois vai adentrando para o escopo da função. por isso esteja voltando sempre indefinido. Alguma solução se for isso Muito Obrigado.

Comment: Pode postar o conteúdo do método AccountAddress?

Comment: EU simplifiquei mais o codigo e expliquei melhor a situação. Obrigado pessoal